# How to do google signing on google play console

Tags: unity-game-engine, keystore, signing

I want to update my app on google play store but they are saying your app was not enrolled in app signing. And I have lost my key store file so how can i update and enrolled in app signing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's impossible. If you lose your key store, you need to create a new app on google play store with a new keystore. Already had this problem and you can't do nothing :s